# How to unit test a variable of type () => void

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am trying to write unit tests for a component that utilizes MediaQueryList. I am struggling to cover one line, which assigns an arrow function to a variable.

I've tried spying on the method inside the function, but I get an error that the method was never called.

My class:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;
  _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  constructor(
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private media: MediaMatcher
  ) {
    this.mobileQuery = this.media.matchMedia('(max-width: 1000px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
}
```

My test:

```js
it('should setup the media query', () => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app = fixture.componentInstance;

  expect(app.mobileQuery).toBeTruthy();
  expect(app._mobileQueryListener).toEqual(/* ??? */);
});
```

I want achieve 100% code coverage, and to do that, I need to cover the assignment of _mobileQueryListener. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to check:

```
it('should setup the media query', () => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app = fixture.componentInstance;

  expect(app.mobileQuery).toBeTruthy();
  expect(app._mobileQueryListener).toBeDefined();
});
```

The `_mobileQueryListener: () => void;` is just declaration and not initialization of the variable. So, check if it defined.

and to verify the behavior of `_mobileQueryListener` to call `detectChanges()`, you can add another test case (make sure to have `public` changeDetectorRef to put `spy` over it):

```
it('should should call "detectChanges()" from "_mobileQueryListener"', () => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app = fixture.componentInstance;
  expect(app._mobileQueryListener).toBeDefined();
  spyOn(app.changeDetectorRef,"detectChanges").and.callThrough();
  app._mobileQueryListener();
  expect(app.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

---

On side note, move below code to `beforeEach()` block, and declare those variables globally

```
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  app = fixture.componentInstance;
```